# Split()-ing in java

Tags: java, split

So let's say I have:

```
String string1 = "123,234,345,456,567*nonImportantData";
String[] stringArray = string1.split(", ");

String[] lastPart = stringArray[stringArray.length-1].split("*");
stringArray[stringArray.length-1] = lastPart[0];
```

Is there any easier way of making this code work? My objective is to get all the numbers separated, whether stringArray includes nonImportantData or not. Should I maybe use the substring method?

Comment: so what is your question? isnt ur current code working?

Comment: My question is if there is shorter way of making this. I don't feel like creating (two arrays when in reality i only need one) is quite efficient.

Comment: are you not overwriting '567' with 'nonImportantData' in the last assignment?

Comment: No... I'm overwriting "567*nonImportantData" with "567" in the last assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the String.split(...) method's argument is not a separator string but a regular expression.

You can use

```
String[] splitStr = string1.split(",|\\*");
```

where | is a regexp OR and \\ is used to escape * as it is a special operator in regexp. Your split("*") would actually throw a java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably remove the unimportant data before splitting the string.

```
int idx = string1.indexOf('*');
if (idx >= 0)
  string1 = string1.substring(0, idx);
String[] arr = string1.split(", ");
```

---

If `'*'` is always present, you can shorten it like this:

```
String[] arr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('*')).split(", ");
```

This is different than [MarianP's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852142/split-ing-in-java/7852310#7852310) because the "unimportant data" isn't preserved as an element of the array. This may or may not be helpful, depending on your application.

Comment: Thanks! I works great :) But somehow still feel like it's a bit too many lines.

Comment: @Yokhen: If you know that `'*'` is always present, you can do it all in one line. Well, you can actually do it in one line anyway, but it's super messy.

Comment: @Yokhen: Okay, added a simpler form for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have the format you've provided....

```
String input = "123,234,345,456,567*nonImportantData";
String[] numbers = input.split("\\*")[0].split(",");
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create two arrays which the OP wanted to avoid? Btw, the answer looks ok.

Comment: I see the OP's comment about avoiding two arrays, which is what my answer does; but it isn't in the question itself.  I just read the question as "give me the numbers" and threw up the cleanest code I could think of.

Comment: well, you figured out that * would not even work. you could write a non-trivial regexp instead of chaining operations.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't recognize the the regular expression of "*" .... I guess I will have to try it another way.

Comment: @MarianP, thank you for pointing out my first item doesn't work.  I'll pull it out of the answer.  I realize doing two splits might not be as efficient as a single regex; but IMO its just a readability thing.  Looking at your answer though, that splits everything and even though it would work in the case provided (nonImportantData in the array at the end) eventually there would have to be a check for something like `for(String val : splitStr) {if(isNum(val)) {doStuff();}}`.  Reason being that I'm guessing nonImportant data could be a lot of diff characters (including what you're...)

Comment: splitting from.  [Apologies for the multiline comment]

Comment: @Yokhen, I've updated my answer with something that should work.  The "*" is a metacharacter and needs to be escaped when using split.  See here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html